# Normal operator and idempotent matrix and self adjoint operator

Tags: linear-algebra

If $T$ is normal operator and $T^3=T^2$,then show that $T$ is idempotent .

1. $TT*=T*T$
2. $T^3=T^2$
3. We are to prove that $T^2=T$

I have tried it many times by operating $T$ in both sides of $1$ and $2$  please tell me what will be the proper way

Comment: If you use the spectral theorem, then $T$ is diagonalisable with eigenvalues 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can prove this in a similar fashion to my answer to your previous question. Note that
$$\|T^2 x - Tx\|^2 = \langle T^2 x - Tx, T^2 x - T x \rangle = \langle T^* T^2 x - T^* Tx, Tx - x \rangle,$$
so it suffices to show $T^* T^2 x - T^* T x = 0$. We have
\begin{align*}
\|T^* T^2 x - T^* Tx\|^2 &= \langle T^* T^2 x - T^* Tx, T^* T^2 x - T^* Tx \rangle \\
&= \langle T^2 x - Tx, TT^*T^2x - TT^*Tx\rangle \\
&= \langle T^2 x - Tx, T^3T^*x - T^2T^*x\rangle \\
&= \langle T^2 x - Tx, 0\rangle = 0,
\end{align*}
completing the proof.

Answer (score 0):

$T^3=T^2$, implies polynomial $p(x)=x^3-x^2$ annihilates $T$, i.e.,
the eigenvalues of $T$ are all in the set $\{0,1\}$.

Given  $TT^*=T^*T$ means that $T$ is normal, i.e. $T=U^* D U$, where $U^*=U^{-1}$ and $D$ diagonal. But all the elements of $D$ are in $\{0,1\}$. Therefore
$$
T^2=U^*DUU^*DU=U^*D^2U=U^*DU=T.
$$